# How to count all the matching sub-string using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to count all instances of a substring from `.PBAAP.B` with P A B in that sequence and can have 1-3 symbols in between them (inclusive).
The output should be 2

1. .P.A...B
2. .P..A..B

What I've tried so far is

```java
return (int) Pattern
                .compile("P.{0,2}A.{0,2}B")
                .matcher(C)
                .results()
                .count();
```

But I only get output 1. My guess is that in both cases, the group is `PBAAP.B`. So instead of 2, I get 1.
I could write an elaborate function to achieve what I am trying to do, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with regex.

```java
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < C.length(); i++) {
    String p = Character.toString(C.charAt(i));
    if (p.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) {

    for (int j = X; j <= Y; j++) {
        if (i + j < C.length()) {
        String a = Character.toString(C.charAt(i + j));
        if (a.equals("A")) {
            for (int k = X; k <= Y; k++) {
            if (i + j + k < C.length()) {
                String b = Character.toString(C.charAt(i + j + k));
                if (b.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return count;
```

Comment: i tested the regex passing it an text like this "PBAAP.B PBAAP.B PBAAP.B" and the count was 3 so seems to work can you share an value of the String that are trying to use the regex

Comment: @RomeoSheshi The 2 should be result for *single* `PBAAP.B` since `"P.{0,2}A.{0,2}B"` there are *two possible matches* for it: (1) using first A like `.P.A...B` (2) using second `A` like `.P..A..B`.

Comment: @OP "but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with regex." even if there is (which I can't guarantee) it would most likely be *way* more complex than your non-regex solution.

Comment: For instance theoretically regex in Java shouldn't be able to match nested brackets, but there are tricks like described at http://www.drregex.com/2017/11/match-nested-brackets-with-regex-new.html which make it possible. But I would still probably prefer to use simple *stack* based solution of my own instead of having to maintain/modify such regex in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you will only get a boolean response out of a regex match - either it is a match or it isn't. Thus, I can't think of a solution solving your problem using regex.

`count()` is used, if you want to check if there are multiple matches at different indices - which is not what you want. For instance, the following snippet will return 2 as `th` is found at 11-12 and at 20-21:

```
Pattern
  .compile("(th)")
  .matcher("let's test this together")
  .results()
  .count();
```

In order to keep the solution without regex readable and extensible, you may want to use regression.

Class to keep track of the latest match of each letter:

```
public class Letter {
  private char letter;
  private int latestMatch;

  // constructor
  // getters + setters
}
```

Class to detect different matches:

```
public class MatchFinder {

  final static String C = "......PAA.BBBadsfjksPeAkBB";
  final static Letter[] LETTERS = new Letter[3];
  final static int SYMBOLS_THRESHOLD = 4;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LETTERS[0] = new Letter('P', -1);
    LETTERS[1] = new Letter('A', -1);
    LETTERS[2] = new Letter('B', -1);
    int count = countMatches(0, C.length(), 0, 0, -1);
    System.out.println(count);
  }

  public static int countMatches(int start, int end, int letterIndex, int currentCount, int latestMatch) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (i < C.length()) {
            Character c = Character.toLowerCase(C.charAt(i));
            if (c.equals(LETTERS[letterIndex].getLowercaseLetter()) && i > latestMatch) {
                LETTERS[letterIndex].setLatestMatch(i);
                if (letterIndex + 1 < LETTERS.length) {
                    int childStart = LETTERS[letterIndex].getLatestMatch() + 1;
                    return countMatches(childStart, childStart + SYMBOLS_THRESHOLD, letterIndex + 1, currentCount, -1);
                }
                currentCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (letterIndex > 0) {
        int parentLetterIndex = letterIndex - 1;
        int latestParentMatch = LETTERS[parentLetterIndex].getLatestMatch();
        if (letterIndex > 1) {
            int parentStart = LETTERS[letterIndex - 2].getLatestMatch() + 1;
            return countMatches(parentStart, parentStart + SYMBOLS_THRESHOLD, parentLetterIndex, currentCount, latestParentMatch);
        } else {
            return countMatches(LETTERS[parentLetterIndex].getLatestMatch() + 1, C.length(), 0, currentCount, latestParentMatch);
        }
    }
    return currentCount;
  }
}
```